# How to validate radio button with text input in PHP

Tags: php, validation

I am try to validate radio button input in PHP but I dont know how because im usually validate the radio button with no input. Im new in this PHP.
this is the picture.

[image: picture of radio button with input]

```
    IF radio name and input name is empty
THEN show error message
    IF radio name or input name is not empty
THEN proceed to insert to the database
```

Comment: What do you mean by "validate radio button input"?

Comment: validate if the radio button and the text input is empty . I tried to validate like that, but it must answer both, which is, one is for the radio button and one is for the text input , i want the validate is like if radio button and the text input is empty, then validate . but if one of the radio button is clicked, then it's not empty.

Comment: maybe like doing so: `if (!empty($_POST['radio_name']) && !empty($_POST['input_name'])) { /*do something*/ }`

Answer (score 0):

Create some radio buttons with the same name.
Ex

```html
<input type="radio" name="animal" value="Lion">
<input type="radio" name="animal" value="Dog">
<input type="radio" name="animal" value="Pig">
```

In your php file, take the value like this(you can use GET or POST)

```html
$_POST['animal']
```

That will return value of selected radio button

Answer (score 0):

This is an example of a validator using jQuery
this is your HTML:

```
//call jquery
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-hwg4gsxgFZhOsEEamdOYGBf13FyQuiTwlAQgxVSNgt4=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<input type="radio" name="radio" value="Yes">
<label for="Yes">Iya/Yes</label>

<input type="radio" name="radio" value="1">
<label for="No">Tidak/No</label>

<button onclick="chek()">KIRIM</button>
```

this is your JavaScript:

```
<script>
function chek() {
var radios = document.getElementsByName("radio");
var formValid = false;

var i = 0;
while (!formValid && i < radios.length) {
    if (radios[i].checked) formValid = true;
    i++;        
}

if (!formValid){ 
alert("anda harus memilih salah satu !");
return formValid;
}
}
</script>
```

or use PHP with the POST method

```
if(!isset($_POST['radio'])){
    //if not clicked
    echo"Tidak boleh kosong";
} else {
    //if clicked
    echo"Radio tidak kosong";
}
```